# checkout specific perforce changelist or label to another disk

Tags: perforce

My perforce workspace is mapped to small disk quota. I want to checkout specific perforce label/changelist to another disk different from the perforce disk since I do not have enough space.

note : I will use the checked files for a while, I do not want to perform any P4 operations on it.

Say my workspace is mapped to
//XYZ/dev/... on a disk /u/p4/...
And I want to checkout label stable_v1 to disk /u/scratch/...
How can I do this.

How to do this as well for a changelist besde the label

Comment: Why not make another, separate workspace, and map it to the /u/scratch disk? Then, when you're done with that workspace, you can delete it.

Comment: Actually I have only a single p4 client file. I need to keep P4 workspace files on P4 disk untouched. If I change the p4 client file to point to scratch, I might lose files on P4 disk. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is to create a temporary workspace to perform the sync operation.

```
p4 -c amr-temp --field "Root=/u/scratch" --field "View=//XYZ/dev/... //amr-temp/..." client -o | p4 client -i
p4 -c amr-temp sync -p @stable_v1
p4 -c amr-temp client -d
```

You can replace `@stable_v1` with `@changelist`, or `@date`, or any other revision specifier.